# Why does NTFS compression not apply to moved files/folders?

Tags: windows, windows-8, ntfs

To save some disk space I designated mostly read-only folder containing portable applications to be compressed. It worked, but now whenever I move new files/folders to the compressed folder I need to re-assign compress property to every moved item. Copied items seem fine.

Anything I can do to fix this behavior?